# Get value of loop options in React

Tags: reactjs

I am looping through an array of objects that return `option` inside a `select` tag. As far as I know, I can't attach event handler on the `option` tag, so I attached onChange handler on `select` tag. I can get the value of `option` tag by default, but as I am looping array of objects, I want to get some other values of the object as well. How do I achieve that?.

Here's the snippet of what I am doing,

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
 {data.map(item => {
   return (
     <option key={item.id} value={item.name}>
       {item.name}
     </option>
   );
 })}
</select>
```

How do I get for example `item.age` and `item.address` when `onChange` get invoked ?

Comment: The option you select is then reflected in select.value, so if you want to get the value  selected this is the way to go

Comment: thanks man, you give me an idea, find the solution already !

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, I set the value of `option` tag as an object, `stringify` it using `JSON.stringify()` so I can get the whole object, and then just read it with `JSON.parse()`

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
 {data.map(item => {
   return (
     <option key={item.id} value={JSON.stringify(item)}>
       {item.name}
     </option>
   );
 })}
</select>
```